# merge bit fields across anonymous structs in C

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, bit-fields, anonymous-struct

I have the following code :

```c
typedef unsigned short u16;

struct S {
    struct {
        u16 a: 9;
        u16 b: 1;
        u16 c: 1;
        u16 d: 1;
    } __attribute__((packed));

    u16 e: 4;

} __attribute__((packed));
```

when I check `sizeof(S)`, it returns 3. is it possible to somehow instruct gcc to merge bitfields across anonymous structs so that `sizeof(S)` returns 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you are looking for can be obtained by making the structure `union` instead, with two bit-fields overlapping. The bits "used" by the first bitfield will be marked as "reserved" in the second one:

```
union S {
    struct {
        u16 a: 9;
        u16 b: 1;
        u16 c: 1;
        u16 d: 1;
    } ;
    
    struct {
        u16 reserved: 12; // Number of bits used in the first struct
        u16 e: 4;
    };
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/XUGWq3)

Comment: `Number of bits used in the first struct`  Beware, though.  Nothing in the C standard guarantees that.  The location of the bits and their order are all implementation-specific.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I guess it is true regarding the relative placement of the `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` fields. But if we had instead `12` bits field, I would think it is pretty safe to assume it will be placed the same way in both structs (hypothetically, as this is not the case here of course)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works great, the only problem is that I have a complex data structure with deeply nested structs and unions and to apply your solution is really hard and make the code even nastier. I thought maybe if there is a gcc option or something

Comment: there is another issue in this case: `struct {
   union {
    struct {
     u16 a: 6;
     u16 b: 3;
     u16 c: 2;
    };
    u16 d: 11;
   };
   u16 e: 1;
  };`, where the sum of bits should be less than 1 byte (of course the rest will be complemented by a higher order structs), but if remove the union and use a flat struct it works as expected `struct {
   u16 d: 11;
   u16 e: 1;
  };`

Comment: the full demo is [here](https://ideone.com/a6Z2oA)